# get words before and after a specific word in text files

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a folder containing some other folders and each of them contains a lot of text files, about 32214 files. I want to print 5 words before and after a specific word and my code should read all of these files.The code below works but it takes about 8 hours to read all of the files and extracts sentences. How can I change the code so that it reads and prints the sentences just in a few minutes? (The language is Persian)

```
.
.
.
def extact_sentence ():
    f= open ("پاکت", "w", encoding = "utf-8")
    y = "پاکت"
    text= normal_text(folder_path) # the first function to normalize the files
    for i in text:
        for line in i:
            split_line = line.split()
            if y in split_line:
                index = split_line.index(y)
                d = (' '.join(split_line[max(0,index-5):min(index+6,len(split_line))]))
                f.write(d + "\n")
    f.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqQkQ.png)

Comment: What makes you think each file can be processed in under 1/1000 of a second?

Comment: I'm not sure there is very much you could do to speed up the code itself, I think the bottleneck is probably the hard-drive access which may be able to speed up with asyncio but I doubt it would give a huge boost to speed

Comment: does `normal_text` load all the files into memory at once? Did you write `normal_text`, optimizations may be doable in there.

Comment: I think if there is a way that I could change "for line in i", the code would work faster

Comment: 50 times faster?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.walk` to access all the files. Then use a rolling window over each file, and check the middle word of each window:

```
import os


def getRollingWindow(seq, w):
    win = [next(seq) for _ in range(window_size)]
    yield win
    for e in seq:
        win[:-1] = win[1:]
        win[-1] = e
        yield win


def extractSentences(rootDir, searchWord):
    with open("پاکت", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        for root, _dirs, fnames in os.walk(rootDir):
            for fname in fnames:
                print("Looking in", os.path.join(root, fname))
                with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as infile:
                    for window in getRollingWindow(word for line in infile for word in line.split(), 11):
                        if window[5] != searchWord: continue
                        outfile.write(' '.join(window))
```

Comment: NameError: name 'infile' is not defined

Comment: @sara: Oops! Fixed now

Comment: excuse me, but there is another error again: win = [seq.next() for cnt in range(11)]
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @sara: that's what I get for using a py2k cookbook on a py3k problem! Try it now

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. It reduced the time to some minutes. But because we did not normalize the code it prints just a few sentences. In Persian, there is a module named "hazm" for normalizing the texts. I tried to use it in this code, but I could not. first I imported it: "from hazm import Normalizer", then I tried to normalize window by writing: normalizer = Normalizer() and then:  window = normalizer.normalize(window), but because it's a list, there was an error. Can you please tell me how to fix it and normalize it. Thank you.

Comment: @sara: I have never worked with Persian text before, and I am unfamiliar with this `hazm` module and what normalization means. I'd recommend you make a new post about that, so that you can reach a wider audience